# Multivariate Limits with the TI nspire CX CAS?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculator

Is there a way to do multivariable limits with the TI nspire CX CAS? I have done some research and the only way I can find is to define $f(x,y)$ and then plug in values for $x$ and $y$, which is a substitution and hence only works for easily determinate limits. How would the CAS do something like $$\lim_{\underbrace{(x,y)\to(3,7)}_{x\neq3}} \frac{xy-3y-4x+12}{x-3}$$

Any help is appreciated!